# single scope Linux DHCP with Microsoft DHCP failover and load balancing

Tags: linux, dhcp, microsoft, scope

Is it possible to run a Linux DHCP server along side a Microsoft DHCP that can be load balanced with failover?

I know you can split the scope but wondering if it possible in a single scope.

Comment: Do they both support the failover standard? https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-dhc-failover-12

Comment: dnsmasq is RFC 2131 compliant https://github.com/imp/dnsmasq/blob/master/src/rfc2131.c
while Mircosoft DHCP is also RFC 2131 compliant

Comment: That's the DHCP protocol spec.  It doesn't discuss failover of servers.